# I need to make a multiple-search on Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, search

I want to make a filter who find some things like status of a work order, employee, month (here I must separate month from the rest of date)

Ok I´m working alone on this project so I need some help.

I´ve got relations on my DB like

employee.employee_id inner join main.employee_id_created (I've made it directly on phpmyadmin)

So I want to search by name of employee but it´s on the other table so when I wanna show results it send me an error

```
    public function()
{
 if($request)
        {
            $query = trim($request->get('searchBy'));
                    
        }
        
        $searchByName = MaintenanceTasks::select('Employee_Id_created')
        ->join('employee', 'employee.Employee_Id', '=', 'maintenance_tasks.Employee_Id_created')
        ->where('Employee_name','like','%'.$query.'%')
        ->get(); 
}
```

blade.php

```
 @foreach($searchByName as $otList)
                    <td>{{$otList->getTaskId()}}</td>
                    @foreach($machine as $machineData)
                @if($otList->Machine_Id == $machineData->Machine_Id)
                @foreach($employee as $employeeData)
                @if($machineData->Employee_Id == $employeeData->Employee_Id)
                <td>{{$employeeData->getEmployeeName()}}</td>
                @endif              
                @endforeach
                @endif
                @endforeach //and so on
```

I would like to make a multiple search using when, but it´s not working

Comment: What the error you got?

Answer (score 0):

you are just selecting **Employee_Id_created** so there is no other data than **Employee_Id_created** in your query result.
Add more columns to **select**.

Answer (score 0):

create multi search

```
if (!empty($req1)) {
    $serach= $serach->where('col', 'like', '%'.$req1.'%');
}

if (!empty($req2)) {
    $serach= $serach->where('col', 'like', '%'.$req2.'%');
}

$serach= $serach->get();
```

**other option**

```
->where([
['col1', 'like', '%'.$req2.'%'],
['col2', 'like', '%'.$req2.'%'],
])
```